# How to reset password for admin with different table in laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have installed fresh laravel and copy all the login,register and password views and contorller for admin login and created table called 'admins'. When i tried to reset the password for laravel default user it works but for 'admins' user it doesn't update the password. And the password resets table is also empty when the default user password is reset.

```
// providers in config/auth.php   

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Dashboard\Admin::class,
    ],
],

// passwords reset in config/auth.php 

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'table' => 'admin_password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],

//Also added broker and guard in ResetPasswordController.php


public function broker()
{
    return Password::broker('admins');
}

protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('admin');
}
```

All i want is to update the admin password and filled the users_reset_table when password is reset. How can i achieve this??

Comment: anyone here who can answer this question..

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Update auth.php
// Providers in config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ]
],


'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\models\Admin::class,
    ]
],
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
],
```

**Setp 2:**
Add two functions in ForgotPasswordController.php

```
/**
 * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
 *
 * @return PasswordBroker
 */
protected function broker()
{
    return Password::broker('admins');
}

/**
 * Display the form to request a password reset link.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function showLinkRequestForm()
{
    return view('auth.passwords.email')->with('user_type', request()->user_type);
}
```

**Setp 3:**
Add two functions in ResetPasswordController.php

```
/**
 * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
 *
 * @return PasswordBroker
 */
protected function broker()
{
    return Password::broker('admins');
}


/**
 * Display the password reset view for the given token.
 *
 * If no token is present, display the link request form.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  string|null  $token
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
        ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email, 'user_type' => $request->user_type]
    );
}
```

**Setp 4:**
//Sending user-type on Blade Template
//admin-show.blade.php from where I want to reset password.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('change-password-form').submit();">
 <span class="fa-passwd-reset">
  <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
 </span> </i> Change Password
</button>

<form id="change-password-form" method="POST"
      action="{{ route('password.email', ['user_type' => 'admin']) }}">
      @csrf
      <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ $admin->email }}">
```

**Setp 5:** //Now open email.blade.php and reset.blade.php inside views/auth/passwords/ and add an hidden input field like so

```
 <input type="hidden" name="user_type" value="{{ $user_type }}" required>
```

Source: https://medium.com/backenders-club/password-brokers-reset-passwords-on-multiple-tables-in-laravel-73068542925c

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the table in your App\Dashboard\Admin Model?

```
protected $table = 'admins';
```

Comment: sorry, but i have tried this but didn't work.. any other ideas??

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to overwrite some methods in `Auth\ResetPasswordController.php`

By the looks of the file, I have a feeling that those two methods should be overwritten.

```
protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('owner');
    }


public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker('admin');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Resetting Passwords for admins table particularly**

Laravel includes `Auth\ForgotPasswordController` and `Auth\ResetPasswordController` classes that contains the logic necessary to e-mail password reset links and reset user passwords. All of the routes needed to perform password resets may be generated using the `laravel/ui` Composer package:

run the below commands:

`php artisan make:notification ResetPasswordNotification`

`composer require laravel/ui`

`php artisan ui vue --auth`
**and**

copy `auth` folder from `resources\views` and named `admin`

**Step 1:** customize the config/auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

    // Admin guards

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],


    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
    ],


    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],


    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

**Setp 2:** ForgotPasswordController.php in `App\Http\Controllers\Admin` Folder

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
 
    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

    public function showLinkRequestForm()
    {
        return view('admin.passwords.email');
    }
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin');
    }
    public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker('admins');
    }
}
```

**And**
ResetPasswordController.php in `App\Http\Controllers\Admin` Folder

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    use ResetsPasswords;

    protected $redirectTo = 'admin/dashboard';

  
    public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
    {
        return view('admin.passwords.reset')->with(
            ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
        );
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin');
    }

    public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker('admins');
    }
}
```

**Setp 3:** Admin.php Model in `App` Folder

**Reset Email Customization**

You may easily modify the notification class used to send the password reset link to the user. To get started, override the `sendPasswordResetNotification` method on your User model. Within this method, you may send the notification using any notification class you choose. The password reset `$token` is the first argument received by the method:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Notifications\ResetPasswordNotification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
    }
}
```

**Setp 4:** web.php route file in `routs` Folder

```
Route::get('admin-login','Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('admin-password/email','Admin\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('admin.password.email');
    Route::get('admin-password/reset','Admin\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('admin.password.request');
    Route::post('admin-password/reset','Admin\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('admin.password.update');
    Route::get('admin-password/reset/{token}','Admin\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('admin.password.reset');
```

**Setp 5:** email.blade.php file in `resources\views\admin\passwords` Folder

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.password.email') }}">
```

**in** reset.blade.php file in `resources\views\admin\passwords` Folder

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.password.update') }}">
```

**and** login.blade.php file in `resources\views\admin` Folder

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.login') }}">
```

**Setp 6:** ResetPasswordNotification.php file in `app\Notifications` Folder
<?php

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;

class ResetPasswordNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    public $token;
    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject(Lang::get('Reset Password Notification'))
            ->line(Lang::get('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.'))
            ->action(Lang::get('Reset Password'), url(config('app.url').route('admin.password.reset', ['token' => $this->token, 'email' => $notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset()], false)))
            ->line(Lang::get('This password reset link will expire in :count minutes.', ['count' => config('auth.passwords.'.config('auth.defaults.passwords').'.expire')]))
            ->line(Lang::get('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.'));
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

**Source:** https://medium.com/backenders-club/password-brokers-reset-passwords-on-multiple-tables-in-laravel-73068542925c